# How to use BETWEEN in a reference table

Tags: sql-server

I was just wondering on how create a query that in such a way it will check if the column is in between in a reference table.

such as

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 BETWEEN ( SELECT Column1 , Column2 FROM TABLE2 )
```

I just don't know how to implement it in a correct way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can have overlapping ranges in `Table2`, and all you want are (unique) `Table1` records that are in any range in `Table2`, then this query will do it.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table2
    Where Table1.Column1 BETWEEN Table2.Column1 and Table2.Column2)
```

You can also solve this using JOINs, if the ranges in Table2 are not overlapping, otherwise you will need to use either `DISTINCT` or `ROW_NUMBER()` to pare them down to unique `Table1` records.

Comment: I dont get the overlapping ranges part but I think this must be safest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try This....

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 as t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Column1 BETWEEN t2.Column1 AND t2.Column2
```

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
SELECT * FROM table1 as t1,table2 as t2
    WHERE t1.Column1 BETWEEN t2.Column1 AND t2.Column2.
```